# Socket.io + the various 'websocket writing' values?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

In the debug of my socket.io app I'm seeing several "websocket writing: 1", "websocket writing: 2", "websocket writing: 5" messages. I've been looking for documentation on what these values represent but haven't found anything useful. Anyone with insight/documentation on these would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are packet codes.
You can see their values in the [source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0.9/lib/parser.js#L16-L26):

```
var packets = exports.packets = {
      'disconnect': 0
    , 'connect': 1
    , 'heartbeat': 2
    , 'message': 3
    , 'json': 4
    , 'event': 5
    , 'ack': 6
    , 'error': 7
    , 'noop': 8
  }
```